# how to explode array with apostrophe

Tags: php, soap-client

[image]

I am making a VAT Checker using this

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl");
```

and in the screenshot, when I explode it like this

`$address = explode(PHP_EOL, $data['address']);`

it will return an error and my request gives 500 error code maybe because of the apostrophe. How can I fix it?

Comment: `when I explode it `. What is "it"?

Comment: please show the code that produces that (what exact?) error.

Comment: also add the string that you are exploding

Comment: I mean, how can I replace the linebreak into space?

Comment: [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)?

Comment: @JonStirling yes but what should I put? I need to change the `nextline` to a `space`

Answer (score 0):

You have not put error message to Your question.

So only clue is dump of address field that tells me that Your issue not related to apostrophe symbol.

As I understood `address` itself is an array. Cause in var dump I see `0 =>` which means that it has `0`-th element in array.

So make a string from array, then replace EOL-s with space:

```
$address = is_array($data['address']) ? implode(', ', $data['address']) : $data['address'];

$address = str_replace(PHP_EOL, ', ', $address);
```